# Issues with Restcomm Docker image

Tags: docker, restcomm

I had a few problems to get the image working. I wanted to share how I solve some and get some help on the one remaining...

**Solved issues:**
On page http://www.telestax.com/rapid-webrtc-application-development-with-restcomm-and-docker there wasn't the proper prefix for name:

```
docker run –name=restcomm -d -e STATIC_ADDRESS=”YOUR_HOST_IP_ADDRESS_HERE” -p 8080:8080 -p 5080:5080 -p 5082:5082 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65535:65000-65535/udp mobicents/restcomm
```

Should have two - in front of name:

```
docker run ––name=restcomm -d -e STATIC_ADDRESS=”YOUR_HOST_IP_ADDRESS_HERE” -p 8080:8080 -p 5080:5080 -p 5082:5082 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65535:65000-65535/udp mobicents/restcomm
```

On https://hub.docker.com/r/mobicents/restcomm/ There are " in the example which make it looks like " are required. In fact no, so we should read :

```
docker run ––name=restcomm -d -e STATIC_ADDRESS=YOUR_HOST_IP_ADDRESS_HERE -p 8080:8080 -p 5080:5080 -p 5082:5082 -p 5080:5080/udp -p 65000-65535:65000-65535/udp mobicents/restcomm
```

Finally, the docker image works like a local install for password, not like an AMI, so you should not use the instance name but 1234 for passwords.

**Remaining Issues:**
Olympus doesn't work: I get 'register failed' which had me thought for a long time I had a password issue until I tried with a remote client and got through.

TTS doesn't work with iSpeech: I didn't managed to get iSpeech to work and had to use VoiceRSS... I didn't get any error message and looking at the restcomm.conf file the parameters seem correct.

Comment: Found a fix for the Olympus issue: the security group 'Restcomm for VoIP Innovations...." had UDP 5082 open but not TCP. Open TCP and now works fine.